# MySQL how to use str_to_date function

Tags: mysql, date

I have to get this select from my DB:

```
SELECT 
    `Atleta`,
    `Medaglia`,
    `Sport`,
    `Evento`,
    `Olimpiade`,
    STR_TO_DATE(`DataGara`, '%d/%m/%y') as Data,
    `Categoria`
FROM `ItalianAthletes` 
WHERE Medaglia <> ''
order by Data asc
```

Previously I made the field 'DataGara' as a Varchar(255) using this format: dd/mm/yyyy.

I'd want in output the same format, but I get yyyy-mm-dd format, with a wrong year, beacuse the year value is 1900 but I get 2019.

I'd like instead the same format as the db, i.e. dd/mm/yyyy and the right year value.

Comment: pls provide your table definition and sample value.

Comment: Format codes are case sensitive.

Comment: Whatever, I suggest you fix the column type before you start getting stored data like `2016-02-31`, `3/4/16`, `earlier today` or `don't know`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use the str_to_date(string, format_mask). Check out http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('February 01 2014', '%M %d %Y');
Result: '2014-02-01'

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('March,8,2014', '%M,%e,%Y');
Result: '2014-03-08'

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Friday, February 28, 2014', '%W, %M %e, %Y');
Result: '2014-02-28'

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014,2,28 09', '%Y,%m,%d %h');
Result: '2014-02-28 09:00:00'

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014,2,28 09,30,05', '%Y,%m,%d %h,%i,%s');
Result: '2014-02-28 09:30:05'

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10,15,30', '%h,%i,%s');
Result: '10:15:30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "%Y", not "%y".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

> %Y    Year, numeric, four digits
>
> %y    Year, numeric (two digits)

```
SELECT 
    `Atleta`,
    `Medaglia`,
    `Sport`,
    `Evento`,
    `Olimpiade`,
    STR_TO_DATE(`DataGara`, '%d/%m/%Y') as Data,
    `Categoria`
FROM `ItalianAthletes` 
WHERE Medaglia <> ''
order by Data asc
```